# twitter Search geocode api returning wrong results

Tags: twitter, location, geocode

I'm using the geocode search api, but its returning tweets which are not actually from around my location.
API : http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=*-filter:replies&geocode=12.9866089,77.5414802,5km&lang=en&exclude_replies=true&rpp=20&result_type=recent

Im trying this from India, however its returning some results from Indonesia. Many people have already discussed about this wrong results problem, but no proper solution is suggested in the context of REST API. However one common thing that I could observe with the wrong results was "geo" tag is null. However its correctly populated for the right results.

Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a long-standing issue, see here:

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/2147

You might try posting there (or at least reading through the thread) for more info.

Cheers